# How to extract specific data in Python from a REST API request

Tags: python, api, rest, request

I'm using a REST API from RapidApi, and I succeded in printing the whole response, but I need only some specific parameters. Like, to print only the Deprature and Arrival times. When using params:{} it doesn't help, because that prints every parameter with the specified argument. I need the inverse, to print a specific parameter with more arguments.

```
import requests
url = "https://timetable-lookup.p.rapidapi.com/TimeTable/LHR/BCN/20221119/"

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "timetable-lookup.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.request("GET",url,headers=headers, params=querystring)
print(response.text)
```

The API response is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OTA_AirDetailsRS PrimaryLangID="eng" Version="1.0" TransactionIdentifier="" FLSNote="This XML adds attributes not in the OTA XML spec.  All such attributes start with FLS" FLSDevice="ota-xml-expanded" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
  <Success/>
  <FLSResponseFields FLSOriginCode="LHR" FLSOriginName="Heathrow Airport" FLSDestinationCode="BCN" FLSDestinationName="Barcelona Airport" FLSStartDate="2022-11-19" FLSEndDate="2022-11-19" FLSResultCount="5" FLSRoutesFound="124" FLSBranchCount="1457" FLSTargetCount="1112" FLSRecordCount="785252"/>
  <FlightDetails TotalFlightTime="PT2H05M" TotalMiles="714" TotalTripTime="PT2H05M" FLSDepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T06:05:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" FLSDepartureCode="LHR" FLSDepartureName="Heathrow Airport" FLSArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T09:10:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FLSArrivalCode="BCN" FLSArrivalName="Barcelona Airport" FLSFlightType="NonStop" FLSFlightLegs="1" FLSFlightDays=".....6." FLSDayIndicator="">
    <FlightLegDetails DepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T06:05:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" ArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T09:10:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FlightNumber="472" JourneyDuration="PT2H05M" SequenceNumber="1" LegDistance="714" FLSMeals="G" FLSInflightServices=" " FLSUUID="LHRBCN20221119BA472">
      <DepartureAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="LHR" FLSLocationName="Heathrow Airport" Terminal="5" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <ArrivalAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="BCN" FLSLocationName="Barcelona Airport" Terminal="1" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <MarketingAirline Code="BA" CodeContext="IATA" CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
      <Equipment AirEquipType="32N"/>
    </FlightLegDetails>
  </FlightDetails>
  <FlightDetails TotalFlightTime="PT2H05M" TotalMiles="714" TotalTripTime="PT2H05M" FLSDepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T07:25:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" FLSDepartureCode="LHR" FLSDepartureName="Heathrow Airport" FLSArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T10:30:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FLSArrivalCode="BCN" FLSArrivalName="Barcelona Airport" FLSFlightType="NonStop" FLSFlightLegs="1" FLSFlightDays=".....6." FLSDayIndicator="">
    <FlightLegDetails DepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T07:25:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" ArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T10:30:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FlightNumber="478" JourneyDuration="PT2H05M" SequenceNumber="1" LegDistance="714" FLSMeals="G" FLSInflightServices=" " FLSUUID="LHRBCN20221119BA478">
      <DepartureAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="LHR" FLSLocationName="Heathrow Airport" Terminal="5" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <ArrivalAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="BCN" FLSLocationName="Barcelona Airport" Terminal="1" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <MarketingAirline Code="BA" CodeContext="IATA" CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
      <Equipment AirEquipType="320"/>
    </FlightLegDetails>
  </FlightDetails>
  <FlightDetails TotalFlightTime="PT2H05M" TotalMiles="714" TotalTripTime="PT2H05M" FLSDepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T10:25:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" FLSDepartureCode="LHR" FLSDepartureName="Heathrow Airport" FLSArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T13:30:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FLSArrivalCode="BCN" FLSArrivalName="Barcelona Airport" FLSFlightType="NonStop" FLSFlightLegs="1" FLSFlightDays=".....6." FLSDayIndicator="">
    <FlightLegDetails DepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T10:25:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" ArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T13:30:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FlightNumber="474" JourneyDuration="PT2H05M" SequenceNumber="1" LegDistance="714" FLSMeals="G" FLSInflightServices=" " FLSUUID="LHRBCN20221119BA474">
      <DepartureAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="LHR" FLSLocationName="Heathrow Airport" Terminal="5" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <ArrivalAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="BCN" FLSLocationName="Barcelona Airport" Terminal="1" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <MarketingAirline Code="BA" CodeContext="IATA" CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
      <Equipment AirEquipType="32N"/>
    </FlightLegDetails>
  </FlightDetails>
  <FlightDetails TotalFlightTime="PT2H05M" TotalMiles="714" TotalTripTime="PT2H05M" FLSDepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T13:15:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" FLSDepartureCode="LHR" FLSDepartureName="Heathrow Airport" FLSArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T16:20:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FLSArrivalCode="BCN" FLSArrivalName="Barcelona Airport" FLSFlightType="NonStop" FLSFlightLegs="1" FLSFlightDays=".....6." FLSDayIndicator="">
    <FlightLegDetails DepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T13:15:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" ArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T16:20:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FlightNumber="480" JourneyDuration="PT2H05M" SequenceNumber="1" LegDistance="714" FLSMeals="G" FLSInflightServices=" " FLSUUID="LHRBCN20221119BA480">
      <DepartureAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="LHR" FLSLocationName="Heathrow Airport" Terminal="5" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <ArrivalAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="BCN" FLSLocationName="Barcelona Airport" Terminal="1" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <MarketingAirline Code="BA" CodeContext="IATA" CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
      <Equipment AirEquipType="320"/>
    </FlightLegDetails>
  </FlightDetails>
  <FlightDetails TotalFlightTime="PT2H05M" TotalMiles="714" TotalTripTime="PT2H05M" FLSDepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T19:20:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" FLSDepartureCode="LHR" FLSDepartureName="Heathrow Airport" FLSArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T22:25:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FLSArrivalCode="BCN" FLSArrivalName="Barcelona Airport" FLSFlightType="NonStop" FLSFlightLegs="1" FLSFlightDays=".....6." FLSDayIndicator="">
    <FlightLegDetails DepartureDateTime="2022-11-19T19:20:00" FLSDepartureTimeOffset="+0000" ArrivalDateTime="2022-11-19T22:25:00" FLSArrivalTimeOffset="+0100" FlightNumber="482" JourneyDuration="PT2H05M" SequenceNumber="1" LegDistance="714" FLSMeals="G" FLSInflightServices=" " FLSUUID="LHRBCN20221119BA482">
      <DepartureAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="LHR" FLSLocationName="Heathrow Airport" Terminal="5" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <ArrivalAirport CodeContext="IATA" LocationCode="BCN" FLSLocationName="Barcelona Airport" Terminal="1" FLSDayIndicator=""/>
      <MarketingAirline Code="BA" CodeContext="IATA" CompanyShortName="British Airways"/>
      <Equipment AirEquipType="32N"/>
    </FlightLegDetails>
  </FlightDetails>
</OTA_AirDetailsRS>
```

How can I write the code to display only the *DepartureDateTime* , *ArrivalDateTime*, and *LocationCode* for the arrival and destination country?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested, I found a solution, I used BeautifulSoup Python library to parse the contents from my XML response. Use the code below as an example:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
for i in range(5):
    print ("Arrivals: ",soup.findAll("flightlegdetails")[i]["arrivaldatetime"])
```

I printed 5 answers from type FlightLegDetail with ArrivalDateTime foobar. This  link could give you some more information:
https://www.projectpro.io/recipes/parse-xml-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing the output using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` package.  From there, you should be able to search through your xml tree to find the relevant data and display it however you wish.

Here's a snippet to get you started:

```
# create element tree object
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
  
# get root element
root = tree.getroot()
```

From there you can search from the root using a tree structure.  The documentation is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html